# Dynamic generated button style class not working

Tags: javascript, css, dynamically-generated

I have 40 dynamically generated buttons that have a class attribute of 'line', the issue is that the style from the line class is not styling the 40 buttons as it is the three buttons that are not dynamically generated. I can see in chrome developer "line" is applied to all 40 buttons.

> javascript:

```js
let buttons = [];
const CLS = ["thin", "button"];
let add_btns = document.querySelector('.add-btn');
add_btns.addEventListener("click", function() {
    let i = 0;
    while (i <= 40) {
        let btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
        buttons.push(document.body.appendChild(btn));
        i++;
        for (let button in buttons) {
            btn.setAttribute('id', "button " + button);
            btn.classList.add(...CLS);
            btn.innerHTML = "Button # " + button;
        }
        btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
            let id = this.id;
            alert("my id is: " + id);
        });
    }
});
```

> css:

```css
html h1,
body h1 {
  margin-top: -5rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: #41403E;
  font-size: 3rem;
}

html section,
body section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
}

html section button,
body section button {
  align-self: center;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 1rem 1rem;
  margin: 0 1rem;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  color: #41403E;
  font-size: 2rem;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 20px 38px 34px -26px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 255px 15px 225px 15px/15px 225px 15px 255px;
}

html section button:hover,
body section button:hover {
  box-shadow: 2px 8px 4px -6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

html section button.dotted,
body section button.dotted.thick {
  border: dotted 5px #41403E;
}

html section button.thin,
body section button.lined.thin {
  border: solid 2px #41403E;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're not appending the buttons to your `section` element. From your CSS, the styles you want will only apply to buttons in the `section` element. But you're appending the dynamically created buttons to the document `body` instead.

Try giving your `section` element an `id`, reference it, and then append the dynamically created buttons to it.

Something like this should work:

```js
let buttons = [];
let section = document.getElementById("section");
const CLS = ["thin", "button"];
let add_btns = document.querySelector('.add-btn');
add_btns.addEventListener("click", function() {
  let i = 0;
  while (i <= 40) {
    let btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    buttons.push(section.appendChild(btn));
    i++;
    for (let button in buttons) {
      btn.setAttribute('id', "button " + button);
      btn.classList.add(...CLS);
      btn.innerHTML = "Button # " + button;
    }
    btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
      let id = this.id;
      alert("my id is: " + id);
    });
  }
});
```

```css
html h1,
body h1 {
  margin-top: -5rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: #41403E;
  font-size: 3rem;
}

html section,
body section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
}

html section button,
body section button {
  align-self: center;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 1rem 1rem;
  margin: 0 1rem;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  color: #41403E;
  font-size: 2rem;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 20px 38px 34px -26px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 255px 15px 225px 15px/15px 225px 15px 255px;
}

html section button:hover,
body section button:hover {
  box-shadow: 2px 8px 4px -6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

html section button.dotted,
body section button.dotted.thick {
  border: dotted 5px #41403E;
}

html section button.thin,
body section button.lined.thin {
  border: solid 2px #41403E;
}
```

```html
<section id="section">
  <button class="add-btn">
Button
</button>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the example. The selectors work when dynamically generatred. I believe you have a problem with nested selectors in the css.

```js
let buttons = [];
const CLS = ["thin", "button"];
let add_btns = document.querySelector('.add-btn');
add_btns.addEventListener("click", function () {
   let i = 0;
  while (i <= 40) {
      let btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
      buttons.push(document.body.appendChild(btn));
      i++;
      for (let button in buttons) {
          btn.setAttribute('id', "button " + button);
          btn.classList.add(...CLS);
          btn.innerHTML = "Button # " + button;
      }
      btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
          let id = this.id;
          alert("my id is: " + id);
      });
  }
});
```

```css
.button {
  padding: 10px;
}

.thin {
  padding: 0px 10px;
}
```

```html
<button class="add-btn button">Add</button>
```